# Good Way to Test Spring Services With Method Level Annotaions

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have a Spring service I want to test that uses the `@Validated` annotation on one of its method parameters.  I would like to test it in the Spring container, but I am not sure if that is the best way.  If testing in the container is the best solution for my situation, I would like to know how to run it in the container without loading my complete configuration.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Spring Test Framework.  I am using the standalone and the web application context of the mock MVC to test my annotations.

**Spring 3.2.4 Test Framework**
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

**Configuration Example**
http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-configuration/